# Slicing 2D Python List

Tags: python, list, slice

Let's say I have a list:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
        [9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

and I would like to get something like:

```
newList =  [[2, 3, 4],
            ['b', 'c', 'd'],
            [8, 7, 6]]
```

hence I tried going with this solution

```
print(list[0:][1:])
```

But I get this output

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 [9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Therefore I tried

```
print(list[1:][0:])
```

but I get precisely the same result.

I tried to make some research and experiments about this specific subject but without any result.

Comment: `print(list(r[1:] for r in ls))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the 1 to end element of **every** row in your matrix.

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
        [9, 8, 7, 6]]

new_list = [row[1:] for row in mylist]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great, I was honestly not aware about the possibility of using a for loop within variable a definition. I would just be curious to understand why in this syntax the order of indexing does not seem to be relevant

Comment: When you chain slices like you tried, you end up slicing the outer most layer: entire rows.  To access the elements within each row, you need to either iterate over each row or use an object/class that supports nested slicing.

Answer (score 2):

I want explain, what have you done by this

```
print(list[0:][1:])
print(list[1:][0:])
```

Firstly note that python use indices starting at 0, i.e. for [1,2,3] there is 0th element, 1th element and 2nd element.

`[0:]` means get list elements starting at 0th element, this will give you copy of list, `[1:]` means get list elements starting at 1th element, which will give you list with all but 0th element. Therefore both lines are equivalent to each other and to

```
print(list[1:])
```

You might desired output using comprehension or `map` as follows

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [9, 8, 7, 6]]
list2 = list(map(lambda x:x[1:],list1))
print(list2)
```

output

```
[[2, 3, 4], ['b', 'c', 'd'], [8, 7, 6]]
```

`lambda` here is nameless function, note that comprehension here is more readable, but might be easier to digest if you earlier worked with language which have similar feature, e.g. [JavaScript's `map`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First - don't name your list "list"!

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    [9, 8, 7, 6]]
b = [x[1:] for x in a]
print(b)
```

[[2, 3, 4], ['b', 'c', 'd'], [8, 7, 6]]

Comment: What's new compared with the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71747864/5929910)

Comment: @mhhabib It was probably written simultaneously - when I started to write it there were 0 answers; but small difference is clearly visible in a first sentence - I'm pointing out to not use list as his name for variable;  I'm not working for SO - I do things on my spare time - I wrote the answer while in a work meeting - may be hit enter late :). If you have time - feel free to combine the answers by adding note about wrong naming of variable.